# ftp_get fetch file on remote server failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, ftp

```
<?php
$local_file = 'filename';
$remote_file = '/folder name/filename';
$ftp_server ='IP';
$ftp_user_name = 'NAME';
$ftp_user_pass = 'PW';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// upload a file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "successfully uploaded $local_file\n";
} else {
echo "There was a problem while uploading $local_file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

I'm using the above  script successfully on a different server with file located in the root folder. But on this one I need to fetch a file that's in a sub-directory (let's say 'folder name' for now). I've tried different things but all throw an error "failed to open stream: No such file or directory".

I've tried:

```
$remote_file = '/folder name/filename.csv';
$remote_file = './folder name/filename.csv';
$remote_file = '../folder name/filename.csv';
$remote_file = '/../folder name/filename.csv';
```

It's my first time dealing with ftp_get command. Can someone please help I'm badly stuck... don't know what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php

Comment: Thanks miken32, that did the trick nicely ;-)

Answer (score -1):

For those who might run into the same issue, I've sorted it out by added the following lines of code (using the function ftp_chdir) and it worked fine:

```
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

echo "Current directory: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";

// try to change the directory to somedir
if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, "Live Stock")) {
    echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
} else { 
    echo "Couldn't change directory\n";
}

// upload a file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "successfully uploaded $local_file\n";
} else {
echo "There was a problem while uploading $local_file\n";
}
```